# How to overlap components with material-ui and react router in react js?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native, material-ui

I'm trying to have my page layout look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FURsD.png). I'm having issues centring it and maintaining the configuration on page resizing.
Here is what I currently have https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-sutherland-whzo4?file=/src/App.js
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Check out [this](https://github.com/innFactory/react-planet#fake-the-space) example in react-planet. I think this is very close to what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: its not quite what I'm looking for but thanks for the suggestion!